# Checking to see if a string is letters + spaces ONLY?

Tags: java, xcode, loops, for-loop, boolean

I want to write a static method that is passed a string and that checks to see if the string is made up of just letters and spaces. I can use String's methods length() and charAt(i) as needed..

I was thinking something like the following: (Sorry about the pseudocode)

```
public static boolean onlyLettersSpaces(String s){
for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
if (s.charAt(i) != a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) {
return false;
break;
}else {
return true;
}
}
```

I know there is probably an error in my coding, and there is probably a much easier way to do it, but please let me know your suggestions!

Comment: Can you use regular expressions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use a regex. This one only matches if it starts with, contains, and ends with only letters and spaces.

```
^[ A-Za-z]+$
```

In Java, initialize this as a pattern and check if it matches your strings.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[ A-Za-z]+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Answer (score 5):

That isn't how you test character equality, one easy fix would be

```
public static boolean onlyLettersSpaces(String s){
  for(i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(ch) || ch == ' ') {
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What is "ch"?*******************

Comment: @user3735218 Sorry, edited. That was a copy paste error. `char ch = s.charAt(i);`

Comment: Character.isLetter() returns true for *much more* than just A-z. Its probably not what the OP needs (I suspect it to be a homework assignment and that the task is to solve both the character ok/bad decision as well as the string loop logic).

Answer (score 0):

For the constraints your mentioned (use of only length() and charAt()), you got it almost right.

You do loop over each character and check if its one of the acceptable characters - thats the right way. If you find a non-acceptable character, you immediately return "false", thats also good. Whats *wrong* is that if you determined to accept the character, you do return true. But the definition says only to return true if *all* characters are accepted. You need to move the "return true" to after the loop (thats the point at which you will know that all characters were accepted)

So you change your pseudocode to:

```
for (all characters in string) {
    if (character is bad) {
        // one bad character means reject the string, we're done.
        return false;
    }
}
// we now know all chars are good
return true;
```

Comment: If I put a return statement inside a loop, will the loop cancel? Hoping it does

Comment: @user3735218 Yes it will. Try to solve it in real code, you will see that a return followed by break gives a compiler error, since the return makes it impossible to ever reach the break.