# check valid name in Java

Tags: java

I want to check valid firstName and lastName. This is the code I implemented which returns false whenever enter digits for firstName and lastName. But it allows the user to include alphabets or whitespace.

The following checkName function when I try to enter digits it still returns true:

```
public static boolean checkValidName(String name){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i){
        char ch = name.charAt(i);
        
        if(!Character.isLetter(ch)){
            return false;
        }   
            
        if(!Character.isWhitespace(ch)){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You `return true` at the end of your for-loop, without any condition. Though "if the first char of name is a letter or whitespace, return true". Your code will only return false, if the **first** char is no letter and no whitespace. Solution: Just remove the `return true` from the for-loop.

Comment: The code you posted always return false (unless you input the empty string) because a character can't be both a letter and a whitespace, so at least one of your inner ifs will return false at the first character. Tested [here](https://ideone.com/8l4xYd). So in addition to takin Benjamin M's comment into account you'll want to merge your two ifs in a single one with the condition `!Character.isLetter(ch) && !Character.isWhitespace(ch)`

Comment: @BenjaminM i tried to remove return true from the loop, but it still having same error

Comment: @高颜值の美食 Yeah, I overlooked what Aaron said: Your code will always return `false`, because of the if-conditions. And if the if-conditions were correct, your code would always return `true` because you unconditionally return true within the loop.

Comment: If the code you posted didn't return false for you, make sure you're not forgetting to compile your updated code before executing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking to see if a string is letters + spaces ONLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191040/checking-to-see-if-a-string-is-letters-spaces-only)

Answer (score 1):

If we want to check for the condition that the `name` should not contain any digits (but can contain special characters like `&`, `%`, `$`, `*` etc).

```
public static boolean checkValidName(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = name.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Since the OP mentioned that the `name` is being validated, I thought that usually names don't contain digits and special characters. If we want to restrict the `name` to ***only*** alphabets and whitespace (no digits and no special characters like `&`, `%`, `$`, `*` etc), then we need to return `false` if the `character` is anything apart from an alphabet or a whitespace.

```
public static boolean checkValidName(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = name.charAt(i);

        // If the character is not a letter and not a whitespace, return false.
        if (!Character.isLetter(ch) && !Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more concise way to match strings to a pattern is using regex.

In this case:

```
return name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+");
```

This regex matches strings that have two words (only english letters, at least one character) separated by one whitespace.
Of course this can be tweaked to fit your needs.