# Take input in String in which Special Charcaters are not allowed(like; ,<>?/ $%^# etc)

Tags: java, string, methods

I want to take input from User in String in which only alphabets, dot(.) and Space is allowed. If User enter any other character expect these, my program should take input from user again. It should continue this process until the user enter the right input(which i want). And at any point if user enter right input it move's further. I tried the given code but it is not working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TourPlanner{

    public static boolean validname(String name){

        String nameUp=name.toUpperCase();
        for(int i=0;i<nameUp.length();i++){

            char charUp=nameUp.charAt(i);

                if(charUp=='A' || charUp=='B' || charUp=='C' || charUp=='D' || charUp=='E' || charUp=='F' || charUp=='G' || charUp=='H' || charUp=='I' || charUp=='J' || charUp=='K' || charUp=='L' || charUp=='M' || charUp=='N' || charUp=='O' || charUp=='P' || charUp=='Q' || charUp=='R' || charUp=='S' || charUp=='T' || charUp=='U' || charUp=='V' || charUp=='W' || charUp=='X' || charUp=='Y' || charUp=='Z' || charUp=='.' || charUp==' '){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }//valid name

    public static void intro(String name, Scanner in){

        validname(name);

        while(validname(name)==false){

            System.out.print("*** Please Enter Name Correctly ***\n");
            System.out.print("What is your Name? ");
            name=in.nextLine();
        }

        String designation;

        System.out.print("Nice to meet you "+name+" Where are you travelling to? ");
        designation=in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Great! "+designation+" sounds like a great trip.");


    }//intro

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("**** Welcome to tour Planner ****\n");
        System.out.print("What is your Name?");
        String name=in.nextLine();
        intro(name,in);
        System.out.println("\n\n********************************************\n");
    }//main
}
```

Comment: What about it is not working? Please be specific about what you expected to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: I want to take input in String in which only alphabets and dot(.) is allowed. but the above code accept any input in String..

Comment: e.g., if i enter "Akif" or "A.k.i.f" then it move further, but if i enter "A>,K" it should stop and take input in that String again to move further.

Comment: Are you understand my question?

Comment: Change `char charUp=nameUp.charAt(i);` for  `char charUp=Character.toLowerCase(nameUp.charAt(i));` then instead of `if(charUp==......` replace it with `if( (charUp >= 'a' && charUp <= 'z') || charUp == '.' || charUp == ' ') return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static boolean validname(String name){
    boolean boo = true;
    String nameUp=name.toUpperCase();
    for(int i=0;i<nameUp.length();i++){

        char charUp=nameUp.charAt(i);

            if(charUp!='A' && charUp!='B' && charUp!='C' && charUp!='D' && charUp!='E' && charUp!='F' && charUp!='G' && charUp!='H' && charUp!='I' && charUp!='J' && charUp!='K' && charUp!='L' && charUp!='M' && charUp!='N' && charUp!='O' && charUp!='P' && charUp!='Q' && charUp!='R' && charUp!='S' && charUp!='T' && charUp!='U' && charUp!='V' && charUp!='W' && charUp!='X' && charUp!='Y' && charUp!='Z' && charUp!='.' && charUp!=' '){
            boo = false;
        }
    }
    return boo;

}//valid name
```

once a method encounters with "return", it stops working and doesn't check other conditions. In your code, your method checks the first letter and decides that it is valid, it returns true and does not check other characters. Because of that, I modified your code and the method creates a boolean value which is initially true. And checks whether an invalid character occurs in input string. After whole loop; if not, it returns true but if it does see an invalid character, boolean value becomes false and at the end of the method, you return it after checking all characters.

Note: String library has some useful functions that allows you to check whether a char is alphabetic, numeric etc. You don't need to write all those characters into an if condition.

Comment: Please write above code in String library which you mentioned above.

Comment: You can check out the function isLetter() [isLetter() usage with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852744/checking-for-is-letter-in-a-string)